# Select list of element and if they have same date, take the most current

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have those 2 tables

```
Period (idPeriod, startDate, endDate)
Person (idPerson, name, idPeriod,...otherInfos)
```

We can have a person in many periods on time.
My actual query is returning one person with the most recent startDate

```
SELECT * FROM person p INNER JOIN period per on per.idPeriod = org.idPeriod
where per.endDate = (SELECT MAX(per.startDate) from per) group by name;
```

How do I retrieve the list of persons. If the person exist more than once, return the one with the most recent startDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, idPerson
FROM Person 
 INNER JOIN Period 
 ON Person.idPeriod = Period.idPeriod
WHERE Period.startDate = 
(
  SELECT MIN(startDate)
  FROM Period AS Per 
   INNER JOIN Person as P
   ON P.id = Per.id
  WHERE P.name = Person.name
)
```

[fiddled](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e686e/7/0)

Comment: it worked but it doesn't take in account if a person exist in one period only http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbb85/1

Comment: @Moh it's broken in your case because you haven't added that period to the `Period` table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.idPerson, MAX(per.startDate) 
FROM person p LEFT JOIN period per on per.idPeriod = org.idPeriod
GROUP BY  p.name, p.idPerson
```